# How to fix not found error

Tags: magento2

I have carefully checked the class but I don't understand why I get an error, this error when I update weltpixel ga4[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following things.

1. Confirm the extension **WeltPixel** file available into your installations.
2. Run the following commands from CLI and then check.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to find the error class exists or not, if not exist then find where this class is implemented.

To Find that class you can run the **grep -r 'GA4\Model\Storage'** search in this way and find the class if exists or not.

If you not find this class then delete the generated and var folder from root then run following commands.

```
php bin/magento s:up;
php bin/magento s:d:c;
php bin/magento s:s:d -f;
```